# Mac OSX (Apple Silicon) Homebrew installed but brew cmd not found

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, homebrew

I have googled around the error I was experiencing but from what I could tell this issue is likely related to how the path in which Homebrew is saved for Big Sur/Apple Silicon is different than other Macbook approaches.

Following the instructions on the [Homebrew page](https://brew.sh/), I ran the `cURL` command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

However, after the operation successfully completed, there was a warning in terminal:
`warning: bin/opt/ path does not exist`

And when I attempted to run a `brew doctor` the command was not found.

It's clear there is a pathing issue, but how do I solve it

Comment: If you use fish, try `fish_add_path --path /opt/homebrew/bin` in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`. `export` worked fine in zsh and bash shells, but caused all kinds of issues in fish. Using `fish_add_path` instead solved my problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this case, I discovered it was a combination of a PATH issue as well as the *.zshrc* file was missing from the `~/` directory

I was able to resolve the issue with these steps.

1. Navigate to `cd /opt/homebrew/bin/`
2. Run `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin`
3. Navigate back to "home" with `cd ~/`
4. in this directory I found that there was *no* .zshrc file (:scream:)
5. So I created a file with `touch .zshrc` and then
6. ran this command: `echo export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin >> .zshrc`

And after running that command, I was able to successfully use the `brew doctor` and other related commands!

Comment: Did it not show this when you run the bash command you showed in your question?

Comment: not sure what "this" is referring to. If you are asking what I saw in the terminal when installing Homebrew thru the `/bin/bash -c` command above was the warning as well as a notification confirming Homebrew had been successfully installed

Comment: I'm saying that during my installation, brew install outputs that you have to add the path to `PATH` variable. And I can see that in the install script as well. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh

Comment: Check the last 5-7 lines of the file

Comment: @AmitSingh, strange, if it was there, I completely missed it. There was no prompt for me to set anything. I also found it strange that there was was no .zshrc file when I `cd ~/` -- I had to create that file manually

Comment: iam using bashrc. this worked for me .Thanks

Comment: This resolved my issue, working on an M1 macOS with zsh shell. Thanks.